# Set value of input field after it is modified by user

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I am able to successfully change the value of an input field *before* it is modified by a user, but after it is modified, the input field retains the user-inputted value - even though it's `value` is changed through JavaScript.

For example, I set the value of the numerical input to be `1801` at the start. Then, the user clicks the up arrow and changes that number to `1802`. Following that (say, on form submission or through an event listener) I attempt to once again change the value of the input (this time to zero).

```
const numberInput = document.querySelector("#shadeDropdown");
numberInput.setAttribute("value", 0);
console.log(numberInput.value);
```

In the console, I can see that the value of the input is indeed zero; shown below.

```
<input class="form-control mr-1 active" type="number" min="0" max="77" value="0" id="shadeDropdown" style="width: 5.5em">
```

However, the input number itself remains at `1802`.

I have tried to first clear the value by setting it to `""`, but that still does not work. Likewise I've tried cloning the node and replacing it, but the user-inputted value stays there.

Is there any simple way to **change the value of an input field after it is modified by the user**?

**Edit**: Setting a time out still does nothing. If I look Inspect the element, it says that it's value is zero (see below):

```
<input class="form-control mr-1 active" type="number" min="0" max="77" value="0" id="shadeDropdown" style="width: 5.5em">
```

However going to the console and typing `document.querySelector("#shadeDropdown").value` returns `1802`.

Comment: The code indeed changes the value. But when it is executed? Make sure it's indeed executed after user changes value. You can see it if you put number attribute change in setTimeout(changeInputToZero, 200);

Comment: @Ava_Katushka This still doesn't work. I've updated the question with some more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is by setting the `value` of the element directly.

```
document.querySelector("#shadeDropdown").value = 0;
```

Will successfully set the value of the input field in the way that simply setting its attribute does not.